# Document source of JSR 345 (EJB 3.2 Final)

Tags: ejb

I am looking for the source version of [JSR 345](https://jcp.org/aboutJava/communityprocess/final/jsr345/index.html) (EJB 3.2 Final) spec. The PDF form uses a font size and layout that was clearly not for human consumption (pt 8 font, really?). It seems that the document was written in some kind of a markup language.

I know that JCP has drafts, and I would be happy with a draft version, too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spec documents (their sources) are in the process of being transferred to Eclipse, but this may still take some time.

IFF the EJB spec is transferred (nothing definitive yet), it should eventually land here: https://github.com/eclipse-ee4j/ejb-api/tree/master/spec

(the current content there is just a skeleton/boilerplate)